# Chrome Extension icon clicked

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I making making a chrome extension and I want to trigger an action when an icon is clicked. I am having some trouble doing this in manifest version 3.

I am currently using the code `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) { alert('icon clicked')});` in my background page and having the active tab permissions. But nothing happens

Comment: Check the console in DevTools.

Comment: Use `chrome.action` and replace `alert` with `console.log`. Note [how to see background.js console?](/a/10258029)